# Can I set CSS rules for sites I don't own?

Tags: css, browser

Consider this case:

I'm using a website service on a daily basis and I don't like the menu background-color.
If I inspect the element I can see that the menu CSS class is called "my-menu" and with a developers tools I can alter the background-color, but obviously, when I'll refresh the page my change will be lost.

Is there a way to define that from now on whenever I surf to this website "my-menu" class will contain my changes? Is there a way to use CSS rules that was not defined in the loaded page and give them the top priority?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a browser extension like `Stylish` and create custom stylesheets (known as userstyles) for it.

[Stylish for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)
[Stylish for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en)

You can find already created userstyles, documentation on creating your own and more in [this](http://userstyles.org/) website.

[Installing & Using Stylish](http://userstyles.org/help/stylish)
[Creating your own userstyles](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish/wiki)
[Userstyles Help](http://userstyles.org/help)

Comment: Does this work for any website?  What CSS styles can you change?  Can you change the width of a div or the display property of any HTML elements?

Comment: Yes, It's up to you what elements and properties you want to override. You just need to have higher specificity in order for them to take precedence over the styles from the website itself. It basically injects a stylesheet in the HTML of the website with your styles (only for your system of course, no one else can see the changes).

Comment: Update: as of Dec 2023 it seems stylish may be outdated. the website does not load properly for me and it seems for others too, the reviews for firefox are overwhelmingly negative recently. vittore's approach worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without additional plugins in Chrome and most likely in Firefox too.

Basically it is natural feature for CSS called user agent stylesheet.

**For [Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/594358/modify-chrome-user-agent-stylesheet)**:

1. go to URL about:version and take note of the "profile path".
2. Browse to the profile path in your file browser. Inside your profile folder, open the User StyleSheets folder. Inside "User StyleSheets", there should be a file called Custom.css, empty by default.
3. Just add your styles in Custom.css.

**For Firefox**:

There are two files

1. `resource://gre-resources/html.css`
2. `resource://gre-resources/quirk.css`

You can find them in the [omni.ja](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29) archive in the Firefox installation folder.

`omni.jar/chrome/toolkit/res`

**For Firefox alternative**:

1. Open dev tools
2. Go to style editor
3. Click `import` button and import your stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

You can with extensions like Stylish and GreaseMonkey, but it'll be possible on your browser only.

With the [GreaseMonkey add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), there's a good wiki which explains how to install a script (*JavaScript*) and customize a web page: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Installing_Scripts. However, you have to deal with Javascript only.

In other hand, **[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/stylish/) allows you to override CSS** (and that's probably what you want first).
Here's an example of stylish config file:

```
@-moz-document domain(stackoverflow.com) {
    body {
        background-color: black !important; // switch to a dark theme for SO
    }
}
```

Stylish is also [available on Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en).

Comment: FYI, Greasemonkey is for javascript not css

Answer (score 0):

sure, the easiest way would be to create a [Chrome extension](http://extensionizr.com/) for Chrome, or if you are using FireFox, you could use ["Grease Monkey"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)

The other, more complex way, is to setup a proxy that will replace the CSS file to your custom file. if you are using windows, I suggest [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), if osx, then use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use Chrome's development tools and edit your css on the `Sources` tab. 
You can edit your code there, you can copy-paste on your css. You can do the same thing on `Styles` properties at right on the development tools doing double click on the style. (:

---

### I work on notepad++ :o

Morning ^^